# How to access google map api in chrome extension. Uncaught reference error , google is not defined

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension.
here is my code.
**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "MyExtension",
   "minimum_chrome_version": "10.0",
  "version": "1.1",
  "description": "Extends the Developer Tools",
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": ["activeTab",
    "<all_urls>",
    "https://google.com/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bg.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*","http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false","<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content_script.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "all_frames": true
  }]

}
```

And I am creating a panel through :: **chrome.devtools.panels.create**
In **Panel HTML** I have specified script to access map API . Like this ::

```
<head>
    <script src="panel.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
</head>
```

In panel.js on some event, I am trying to access inspectedWindow
**panel.js**

```
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval("setRedSelectedElement($0)",{ useContentScriptContext: true });
```

**content_script.js**

```
  var ownerdocument;

    function setRedSelectedElement(el) {
        ownerdocument= el.ownerDocument;
        ownerDocument.body.style.backgroundColor = "**red**";
        alert("style updated ");
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(26.449895, 74.639916);
        alert("success -- "+latlng);
    }
```

On new google.map.LatLng execution , extension is failing.
***Uncaught reference error :: google is not defined***
How extension can access google api.

Comment: Your content script definition is weird. Just use `"matches": "<all_urls>"` instead of specifying `"<all_urls>"` along with others, it is meaningless. Same for the `"permissions"` key.

Comment: The problem is that you defined the Google Maps API script to run within your panel, but your content script expects it to be there. However, the content script is unrelated to your panel. You need to run Google Maps API within the content script. I am not sure this is possible using the remote file, you will have to embed the script within your extension (I am not sure this is allowed by Google Maps, you should check that) and add it to the `"js"` array key within your content script definition.